# Adding an image file (.PNG) programatically in Qt Creator using QPixmap and QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Good morning all,

I am having trouble adding a .PNG file to my Qt Creator project using the QPixmap and QLabel method. The different ways I've tried to do this (in code snippet format) appear below.

System: Raspberry Pi 2 running Debian Wheezy
Builder: Qt Version 4.8.2 For Embedded Linux
Compiler/Tool Chain: GCC/G++ 4.9.2

```
code snippet 1
1 #include <QtGui/QApplication>
2 #include <QPixmap>
3 #include <QLabel>
4 #include <wiringPi.h>
5 #include "mainwindow.h"
...
187 QLabel myLabelPi;
188 QPixmap myPixmapPi = new QPixmap(":/GPIOGUI/rpi2.png");
189 myLabelPi.setPixmap(myPixmapPi);
190 myLabelPi.setScaledContents(true);
191 myLabelPi.show();
```

---

```
code snippet 2
1 #include <QtGui/QApplication>
2 #include <QPixmap>
3 #include <QLabel>
4 #include <wiringPi.h>
5 #include "mainwindow.h"
...        
187 QLabel myLabelPi;
188 QPixmap *myPixmapPi = new QPixmap(":/GPIOGUI/rpi2.png");
189 myLabelPi.setPixmap(myPixmapPi);
190 myLabelPi.setScaledContents(true);
191 myLabelPi.show();
```

---

The errors I get with each of these codes when they compile (respectively) are:

code snippet 1:
/home/pi/gpioGUI/main.cpp:187: error: conversion from 'QPixmap*' to non-scalar type 'QPixmap' requested

code snippet 2:
/home/pi/gpioGUI/main.cpp:188: error: no matching function for call to 'QLabel::setPixmap(QPixmap*&)'
candidate is:
void QLabel::setPixmap(const QPixmap&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QPixmap*' to 'const QPixmap&'

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: In your second example change `myLabelPi.setPixmap(myPixmapPi);` to `myLabelPi.setPixmap(*myPixmapPi);`

Comment: Nobody seems to have pointed you to the better approach, which is not using a pointer for your `QPixmap`. You could initialize it with `QPixmap myPixmap(":/GPIOGUI/rpi2.png");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the errors carefully, most of the times it contains what is wrong.

Line 188 : `new` returns a pointer. Hence your variable should be a pointer (with a `*` )

```
QPixmap* myPixmapPi = new QPixmap(":/GPIOGUI/rpi2.png");
```

In line 189, it also says what's wrong. You're passing a pointer where a reference is expected. (I haven't tested the code though)

```
myLabelPi.setPixmap(*myPixmapPi);
```

Try this and see.

Comment: Thank you very much Praneeth. In this instance, I am guilty of just shoehorning some copy-paste into my code, and not taking the time to understand. In the future, I will do more learning before asking my questions. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. What I meant was that the compiler error is very useful (most of the times) when tracking errors. So read it first. :)